# Jquery validate not working on bootstrap-tokenfield

Tags: jquery, validation

In my web application I have a format in one input bootstrap-tokenfild. Tokenfild works fine for me.
I validate the form with jquery validate. Jquery validate also works correctly on other inputs.

Unfortunately jquery validate does not work on the bootstrap-tokenfield(input).
The input is set to required: true.

```
$.validator.addMethod("selectOnlyOnceCat", function(value, element) {
    return $('#mec_fes_form input[name^="mec[categories]"]:checked').length == 1;
}, '(*) check one.');

$.validator.addMethod("selectOnlyOncePrice", function(value, element) {
    return $('#mec_fes_form input[name^="mec[labels]"]:checked').length == 1;
}, '(*) check one.');


$.validator.addMethod("speakersAjaxId", function(value, element) {
    return $.trim($('#speakersAjaxId').val()).length>0;
}, '(*) add minimum one');



var tmpChecks = [], myRules = [], tmpChecksLabels = []; 
$('#mec_fes_form input[name^="mec[categories]"]').each(function(){
   tmpChecks.push(this.name); 
   myRules[$(this).attr("name")] = {
    require_from_group : [1, ".selectOnlyOnceCat"]  
   }; 
});

$('#mec_fes_form input[name^="mec[labels]"]').each(function(){
   tmpChecksLabels.push(this.name); 
   myRules[$(this).attr("name")] = {
    require_from_group : [1, ".selectOnlyOncePrice"]  
   }; 
});




var checkboxes = $('.selectOnlyOnceCat');
var checkbox_names = $.map(checkboxes, function(e,i) { return $(e).attr("name")}).join(" ");
var lastCheckboxParent = checkboxes.last().parent();

var checkboxesPrice = $('.selectOnlyOncePrice');
var checkbox_names_Price = $.map(checkboxesPrice, function(e,i) { return $(e).attr("name")}).join(" ");
var lastCheckboxParent_price = checkboxesPrice.last().parent();

$("#mec_fes_form").validate({
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
        'speakersAjaxName': {
            required: true,
            'speakersAjaxId': true
        },
        myRules
    },   
    groups: {
        selectOnlyOnceCat: tmpChecks.join(' '),
        selectOnlyOncePrice: tmpChecksLabels.join(' ')
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr("type") == "checkbox" && element.attr("class") == "selectOnlyOnceCat error"){ 
               error.insertAfter(lastCheckboxParent);
           }else if (element.attr("type") == "checkbox" && element.attr("class") == "selectOnlyOncePrice error"){
                error.insertAfter(lastCheckboxParent_price);
           }else if(element.attr("type") == "text" && element.attr("name") == "speakersAjaxName"){
                error.insertAfter(element);
           }else{
               error.insertAfter(element);
           }
    }, 
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator){
            var actualElement = validator.errorList[0].element.id;
            var position = $('#'+actualElement).position();
            
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: position.top }, "slow");
    }
});
```

When the input is empty and I click SUBMIT the form is sent - which it shouldn't be.I do not want to do this. I want at least one token to be entered - selected.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000726/required-field-not-working-with-bootstrap-tokenfield

Comment: This solution you have showed is for the standard HTML5 validation. This validation works for me as well. Unfortunately I do not want to use this validation. I use jquery validate which gives me more features. Unfortunately using jquery validate stops working tokenfield validation.